# synchronization between text appearn and audio in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Is there any way to sync audio with text. I have to highlight text word by word for audio file. Text is shown in textview & audioPlay function is implmented in android.
thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do it directly from the audio file with some sort of bookmark.

You can always mimic the way they do it with subtitles. That is, create a file containing a mapping TIME->String, then you load this file into a runtime data structure and using the framework timer utilities you synchronize the text with the file.